# Trying to locate sql injection source

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection

My site is being attacked via sql injection, I'm trying to locate the source of the injection..

The query being sent is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM settings
WHERE user =  'x'
XOR SLEEP( 15 ) 
LIMIT 1 #'
```

I'm new to injection but I assume they are tagging the end of one of my queries?

What can I do to find out where this is coming from, I thought maybe it was my login page but my login page doesn't access the settings table in any queries.

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you directly enter the X value? As in user = '. $user .' or something like that? Because that would be the source obviously

Comment: Might be good to tag the language of your webpage, as how you prevent SQL injections varies wildly from one language to another.  A very high level chunk of advice would be to look where raw SQL commands are being created and aren't being parameterized and/or aren't being passed through as prepared statements.

Comment: What SQL DBMS is this?  You options vary widely based on the actual SQL product.

Comment: My apologies I'm using PHP/MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somethings wrong with your SELECT; everything after the second `'` is bad.

You probably have something like this PHP example:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user = '$user'";
```

(The concept is the same in other languages, but you didn't say which language you're using.)

Exploiting this is easy; just pass something with `'` in the `user` form field. In your example, the attacker is using a [timing attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blind_SQL_Injection) to see if the username `x` exists. They then use `#` to turn the rest of the line into a comment, avoiding a syntax error on the final `'`.

To prevent this, use prepared statements. You will want to read the [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), too.

Comment: That is very helpful information, now my issue is i'm trying to locate exactly where this "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user = '$user'";  is at, our site has hundreds of pages with thousands of lines, and most settings pages are located after a login is required.

Comment: You can start by searching for `SELECT * FROM settings`. If your editor allows regular expression searches, try `SELECT\s+\*\s+FROM\s+settings`. (If it doesn't, get a new editor!) You're going to need to replace *every* SQL statement that uses simple concatenation to build a query.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't matter if the login page isn't using the settings table, for example:

instead of entering an email someone enters this instead into the input -

```
 x'; SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user =  'x' XOR SLEEP( 15 ) LIMIT 1
```

Then your login query would look like

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE password = 'x' and email ='x'; SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user =  'x' XOR SLEEP( 15 ) LIMIT 1 #';
```

both queries get excuted.

I got hit by sql injection several years ago.... lesson learned. 
I'm always using pdo and prepared statements now.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I will look into prepared statements.